# Classification of 1st order non linear system of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the non linear, 1st order PDE system

\begin{align}
\xi_u^2+\eta_u^2=\xi_v^2+\eta_v^2=\left(1+\frac{\xi^2+\eta^2}{4} \right)^2,
\end{align}

for $\xi=\xi(u,v)$ and $\eta=\eta(u,v)$, with $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$. What type of system is it ? Most common PDE classification rules apply to second order equations, linear or semi-linear, which is not the case here. Alternatively, what are the conditions for existence and uniqueness of the solutions on some (compact, although not necessarily) $(u,v)$ domain ?

Comment: This is called the [Eikonal equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation). It's a fairly well studied problem so I'm sure you can find the answers to your questions through a Google search.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thank you. Here the gradient of none of the functions involved, also the function itself appears, how can this be an Eikonal equation or system of equations ?

Comment: You are right, I misread the question, it is not the Eikonal equation though it is similar. This is a first order, fully nonlinear system of PDEs.